# postgresql error: column "" does not exist in where clause

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, koa

I'm trying to check if email already exists and i'm sending **daniyal@gmail.com** in email parameter but getting error column "daniyal" does not exist.

```
ctx.app.pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = " + ctx.request.body.email, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                ctx.body = {
                    status: 500,
                    message: 'Something went wrong'
                };
                console.log('Query Error: ', err);
                throw err
            } else {
                ctx.body = {
                    exceptions: "",
                    status: 200,
                    error: false,
                    message: "user already exists with this email",
                };
            }
        });
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  That will prevent hard-to-debug syntax errors in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate issue is that you are missing single quotes around the value that you are passing (hence, Postgres considers it a column name).

But for this, you *do* want to use a parameterized query, for both security and efficiency

```
ctx.app.pool.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", 
    [ctx.request.body.email], 
    function(err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            ctx.body = {
                status: 500,
                message: 'Something went wrong'
            };
            console.log('Query Error: ', err);
            throw err
        } else {
            ctx.body = {
                exceptions: "",
                status: 200,
                error: false,
                message: "user already exists with this email",
            };
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: getting Query Error:  error: syntax error at end of input

Comment: I just removed the console.log and throw err. why i'm not going in else part with the email already exists?